# One function parsing character to Unicode works in Eclipse but not in JDeveloper?

Tags: java, unicode

I have met a strange problem. Please see the code below:

```
public static String toUNICODE(String s) {
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
  for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
    if(s.charAt(i)<=256) {
      sb.append("\\u00");
    } else {
      sb.append("\\u");
    }
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(s.charAt(i)));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

It's parsing characters to Unicode. It works well in Eclipse. But when I test it in JDeveloper IDE, I get the wrong result. For example, in Eclipse I will get `\u6211` when the input is "我", which is the right answer. Whereas I will get \u00e6\u2c6\u2018 in JDeveloper.

Please enlighten me why.

Comment: How to you enter this character? Do you enter it by hand? Try to debug this function and check that input is the same in both environments.

Comment: yes. I entered the argument by hand.
one more clue for you: in Jdeveloper, the simple code `System.out.print(“我”)` will print ??.

Comment: Have you checked Jdeveloper IDE character encoding type? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14693/appa_configuring_jdev.htm

Comment: Yes. the default encoding is GBK and I change it to UTF-8. But problem still

Comment: @Tom: Not an answer but a suggession. As jDeveloper is priting ?? for System.out.print(“我”) then instead of program you should rather focus on if jDeveloper editor supports that character.

Comment: @Parvez: Do you mean JDeveloper doesn't support chinese? then what shoud i do

Comment: 我 is E68891 in UTF-8, and strangely enough the first character you are getting in JDeveloper is 0x00E6. Which makes me think you are getting some (mangled) UTF-8 instead of UTF-16.

Comment: @Tom: I don't know, I was just giving suggestion that you may focus on sysout first rather than the toUNICODE() method. I don't have JDeveloper on my machine so can't test it.

Comment: Can you try this piece of code in JDeveloper and see what is printed.   PrintStream ps = null;
  try {
   ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException error) {
   System.err.println(error);
  }
  ps.println("我");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you interpret the UTF-8 bytes of `"我"` (`0xE6 0x88 0x91`) as Windows-1252, you will get `"æˆ‘"`

When you pass `"æˆ‘"` to your function, the result is `\u00e6\u2c6\u2018`. So somewhere you are 
inputting UTF-8 but the program is simply interpreting it in Windows-1252.

There is no info in your question about how you are doing input or reading it, but this should be very simple to solve once you do add that info.

Btw, your function is broken for code points in the 0x100-0xFFF range, leaving out padding for those. As well as code points beyond 0xFFFF.

Comment: Yes, your answer gave a thought. And for guys who using JDeveloper, this is also useful.<br/>
In JDeveloper, there are two place to set encoding:<br/>
1st is in Tools>Preferences, to set the editor encoding.<br/>
2nd is in project properties>Compiler, to set the encoding to compile java file.<br/>
What causes my problem is 1st is set to UTF-8 and 2nd is set to cp1521<br/>
Thanks for all your guys' help